# Valor no se muestra como debe ser

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas, tengo un código el cual me esta dando un problema.

Mi código se compone de 3 cosas, una variable total, otra para dinero recibido y otra para mostrar cambio o pendiente de pagar (dependiendo el resultado que me de al verificar el total y el dinero recibido), por ejemplo si mi total es = 500, mi recibido = 400 my otra variable debe ser = Falta por pagar: 100.

Hasta ahora tengo un código funcionando pero el detalle es al mostrar esta ultima variable, me muestra el resultado correcto pero no logro hacer que muestre si es cambio o si es dinero pendiente de pagar, también el resultado que me da es un numero entero negativo, quisiera que si fuera cambio se mostrara sin lo negativo.

[Aquí tengo un ejemplo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WjGgeV)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var dolar = 17.50;
  
  $('#Total').on('keyup', function() {
    var valor = $(this).val();
    
    if (valor == "") {
      $('#TotalLbl').text("$00.00");
    } else {
      $('#TotalLbl').text("Total: $" + parseFloat(valor).toFixed(2));
    }
  });
  $('.money').on('keyup', function() {
    var dollar = $('#USD').val() * dolar;
    var mx = $('#MXN').val();
    valor = parseFloat(mx) + parseFloat(dollar);
    
    if (valor == "") {
      $('#Received').text("$00.00");
    } else {
      $('#Received').text("Received: $" + parseFloat(valor).toFixed(2));
      var falta = ($('#Total').val() - valor);
      var tot = $('#Total').val(); 
      console.log(falta);
      if (parseFloat(falta) < parseFloat(tot))
        $('#INeedThisTo0').text("Cambio: $" + parseFloat(falta).toFixed(2));
      else
        $('#INeedThisTo0').text("Pendiente: $" + parseFloat(falta).toFixed(2));
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input placeholder="Total.." type="number" id="Total" />

<input placeholder="MXN.." type="number" class="money" id="MXN" />

<input placeholder="USD.." type="number" class="money" id="USD" />

<br>

<label id="TotalLbl"></label>

<label id="Received"></label>

<label id="INeedThisTo0"></label>

<label id="Change"></label>
```

Comment: ¿Cuán es el flujo de tu aplicación? ¿Qué proceso tiene que pasar cuando sa cambian cantidades en MX y USD?

Comment: @GustavoGarcía El total es automático al scanear unos productos pero en este caso lo hice para que sea escribiendo el valor, el usuario puede ingresar cantidades tanto en MXN y en USD por ejemplo, me dan $100 MXN y $2 USD o $100 MXN y USD queda vació y así consecutivamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que según la lógica que tienes implementada, la comprobación del `if` siempre va a ser `true`, por lo que no se ejecuta nunca la sentencia declarada en el `else`. Una posible solución podría ser comprobar si el valor que falta es mayor o menor que 0.

Algo así:

```
if (parseFloat(falta) < 0){
    $('#INeedThisTo0').text("Cambio: $" + parseFloat(falta).toFixed(2));
  } else {
    $('#INeedThisTo0').text("Pendiente: $" + parseFloat(falta).toFixed(2));
  }
```

Y para mostrar un valor positivo, simplemente multiplica por (-1):

```
if (parseFloat(falta) < 0){
    $('#INeedThisTo0').text("Cambio: $" + parseFloat(falta).toFixed(2));
  } else {
    $('#INeedThisTo0').text("Pendiente: $" + (parseFloat(falta).toFixed(2) * (-1)));
  }
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer positivo un valor negativo:

```
 $('#INeedThisTo0').text("Cambio: $" + parseFloat(falta * (-1)).toFixed(2));
```

Un saludo